# Compress a PDF with GhostScript 10.01.1 : Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: pdf, compression, ghostscript

I'm trying to compress some PDF files with Ghostscript 10.01.1.
The command line works for many files, but I sometimes have an error. Here is the command line :

```
-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dCompatibilityLevel=1.3 -sOutputFile="output.pdf" -dBATCH "input.pdf"
```

I tried other values for the option -dPDFSETTINGS like /screen or /printer, and I still have the same error.
I uploaded the PDF file I'm trying to compress. Do you guys would have a solution ?

Here is the link to the PDF file : https://transfert.free.fr/jbAbj3z
I have the feeling Ghostscript fails when the PDF contains almost only pictures.

Kind regards.

Comment: Your file and command works perfectly well for me. You haven't said which OS you are using nor where you sourced Ghostscript from. Please note that Ghostscript's pdfwrite device does not 'compress' PDF files. Judicious use of the settings can produce a smaller file at the cost of quality and sometimes the output will be smaller than the input, but that is not guaranteed. There's really no point in PDFSETTINGS=/defulat since that is (obviously) the default. Also, why are you setting CompatibilityLevel to 1.3 ? That will probably produced **larger** files

Comment: You probably want to either add -dNOPAUSE as well, or use '-o output.pdf' and drop -dBATCH because -o includes -dBATCH and -dNOPAUSE. Your PDF file doesn't seem to include any images (pictures) at all as far as I can see. It's entirely text and linework.

Comment: Hi KenS, thanks for answering me. You're right there is no picture in this file sorry, my bad. Yes I know it's not to compress but with my files, that's what it does. I'm using Windows 10 and I used the official Ghosscript website https://www.ghostscript.com/releases/gsdnld.html  : https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs10011/gs10011w32.exe

Comment: Hmm well that's the binary I tested with and it works absolutely fine for me. Although I used the 64-bit executable, are you using 32 or 64-bit ? Ah, I see you are using the 32-bit executable.

Comment: Well the 32-bit executable works for me too, what do you see on stdout ? I'm assuming you are using gswin32c, not gswin32, if you are using the windowed executable then what comes up in the window ?

Comment: KenS, you gave me the answer ! I did'nt check the stdout and here is the content :  Error: /undefinedfilename in (D:\\\\PDF_2\\\\NTD0002_202304_synthese_heures_et_frais_BIENVENU_PATRICE)\nOperand stack:\n\nExecution stack:\n   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push\nDictionary stack:\n   --dict:770/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--\nCurrent allocation mode is local\nLast OS error: No such file or directory\n

Comment: When I uploaded the file I renamed it "input.pdf". But the original name is "NTD0002_202304_synthese_heures_et_frais_BIENVENU_PATRICE MICHEL.pdf". Is there an issue with the filename size ?

Comment: Shouldn't be, but the obvious test would be to rename it to a smaller filename and try that. There is a limit on the length of a command line in Windows and Linux

Comment: Yep, I did the test with a shorter name and that's good. But I would like to know if the problem is with the command line in Windows, or with GhostScript, and if there is a work around. Because I don't have the hand on the access path and the file names the final user will use

Comment: The problem isn't with Ghostscript I shouldn't think, it will be the command line limit. You can use the @file syntax for Ghostscript instead. That allows you to put all the commands (including the filename) in a file and then tells Ghostscript to process the file contents as if they had been the command line. There's no practical limit on that. This option in Ghostscript exists, of course, precisely because of the limit on the shell command line.

Comment: Hi, sorry to reply late. KenS, I made a little test and it appears the problem has nothing to do with the length of the command line. The problem is with the space character in "NTD0002_202304_synthese_heures_et_frais_BIENVENU_PATRICE MICHEL" between PATRICE and MICHEL. I had a look at all the files in error, and that's the same disease : they all contain at least one space character . If I replace the space by an underscore, Ghostscript processes it correclty. So I guess there is something wrong with Ghostscript's charset, don't you think ?

Answer (score 0):

The real issue here is the total length of your command line and how it's composed for a Windows cmd shell.

There are tricks to reduce both problems, some will help more than others.

Traditionally before LFN (Long File Names) in Windows file names were short, taking this example it may be D:\PDF\NTD0002_202304_synthese_heures_et_frais_BIENVENU_PATRICE MICHEL.pdf however the system will need to add any mapped folders for that drive and all those nested network folders too. Also if any are UTF-encoded they will increase the hidden length.

[image]

So it is common when people try to access long names in deeply nested folders that Acrobat often cannot read the file, or resave after modifications, thus losing hours of commenting etc.

The second problem you will often encounter is, Widows Command Line needs "Filenames" with certain characters enclosed in "Double Quotes", especially as here with a space in the file allocation label.

So to provide a short command we need to lengthen parts with `"` but omit many other string lengths.

Thus by invoking a remote GS###.EXE (ideally itself in a short path) from the target directory, we can reduce command length favourably, and as required the file has drastically had all the unwanted compliancy parts removed so almost 4 KB is now under 1 KB.

[image]

The best way to manage a long GhostScript command line is to use a GhostScript parameters file say like this where the result will be the same.

`"C:\Apps\PDF\GS\gs10011w32\bin\gswin32c.exe" @params.txt`
where `params.txt` contains in this case

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite
-dPDFSETTINGS=/default
-dCompatibilityLevel=1.3
-o "output.pdf"
"NTD0002_202304_synthese_heures_et_frais_BIENVENU_PATRICE MICHEL.pdf"
```

[image]

So exactly what is removed for these files? we can see from before and after analysis. Note it will vary highly for each given case.

Much of the unnecessary broken line duplication is actually retained as it would destroy the linework appearance, however as totally rewritten it's generally written with less unnecessary zero padding. The greatest gain appears to be discarding much of the font characteristics although there are only 3 CID names defined both before and after.

[image]

Comment: Hi K J, thank you for this very detailed answer.
However, how would the command line look like if I wanted to use "double quotes" as you said, and not a parameters file ? Because I tried to add two quotes, and it did'nt work.

Comment: Hi K J, everything is fine now. I had a syntax problem in the command line using quotes. It works perfectly now, even with space character in filename. Once again, thanks for your precious help, that's very kind of you :-)